# Using Git in VS code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Here is the problem:
In VS code, I want to use git
I have 2 branches: master & step01 (as you see in the picture)
When I change something in branch step01, for example, and then change the branch, I see that the same change has applied in the branch master!
Why is it happening and how can I know that which change is for which branch?

P.S: I know that it's because I'm new with git and I don't understand it very well and I hope that you can help me understand. thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, if you edit something in branch `step01`, then checkout to `master`, you have some changes file, but it just changed in your local computer only. Changes here means the different from current file state to original state.

Then you check out back to branch `step01`, and commit it to `step01`, nothing will change in your `master` branch, your changes will be pushed to branch `step01` only.

Is there anything else that confusing you about git?

Comment: So, in this case, we need to have a git server with an original file that won't change, am I right? and then, All the changes will be applied on my computer! If my conclusion is wrong, please tell me.

Comment: You will need an git remote (git server - in your idea), there's too many git remote server like github. bitbucket... etc. If you want to come back to the original content, you can check out to `master` branch, then check out to a new branch (becase `master` is a main branch, we shoud not commit directly to this branch), may be `step02`. Then your branch `step02` will have the old code. If you want to have the edited code, just checkout to the branch `step01`.

Comment: And remember, if you `commit` changes, it commited to your local only. When you pushed to remote, it changed in the remote server (where other user can see it)